# Reading JSON as a config, returns value null and crashes

Tags: c#, json, .net

I'm having a bit of a problem with using JSON as a config (Can't be asked to have my users of this program use Config.config or Program.exe.config at the moment, and JSON is easier to read in my opinion. So here's the code:

```
    public static Bot bot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Bot>(File.ReadAllText("Bot.config"));
    public static string nick = bot.configuration.BotName;
```

string nick is returned and this is the error I get when I run the program:

> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer fo
>   r 'Bot.Program' threw an exception. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Objec
>   t reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Bot.Program..cctor() in Program.cs:line 38
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Bot.Program.Main(String[] args)

That's the problem I've been having for a bit.

Classes:

```
 public class Bot
    {
        public Configuration configuration { get; set; }
        public Welcomesystem welcomeSystem { get; set; }
        public Twittersystem twitterSystem { get; set; }
        public Youtubesystem youtubeSystem { get; set; }
        public Weathersystem weatherSystem { get; set; }
        public Loyaltysystem loyaltySystem { get; set; }
        public Urldetection urlDetection { get; set; }
        public Commands commands { get; set; }
    }
    public class Configuration
    {
        public string BotName { get; set; }
        public string Channel { get; set; }
        public string Server { get; set; }
        public string OAuth { get; set; }
        public string BotAdmin { get; set; }
        public string _comment1 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Welcomesystem
    {
        public bool enabled { get; set; }
        public bool forSubsOnly { get; set; }
        public bool forRegOnly { get; set; }
        public string DefaultWelcome { get; set; }
    }
    public class Twittersystem
    {
        public bool enabled { get; set; }
        public string _comment2 { get; set; }
        public string APIKey { get; set; }
        public string APISecret { get; set; }
        public string TokenKey { get; set; }
        public string TokenSecret { get; set; }
    }
    public class Youtubesystem
    {
        public bool enabled { get; set; }
    }
    public class Weathersystem
    {
        public bool enabled { get; set; }
        public string authKey { get; set; }
        public string _comment3 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Loyaltysystem
    {
        public bool enabled { get; set; }
        public string _comment4 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Urldetection
    {
        public bool enabled { get; set; }
        public string defaultTimeout { get; set; }
        public string _comment5 { get; set; }
    }
    public class Commands
    {
        public bool Diablo_Command { get; set; }
        public bool Warcraft_Command { get; set; }
    }
```

And the JSON File:

```
{
  "Bot": {
    "configuration": {
      "BotName": "Trub0t",
      "Channel": " ",
      "Server": " ",
      "OAuth": " ",
      "BotAdmin": " ",
      "_comment1": "You can get your oauth code for your bot at http://twitchapps.com/tmi/"
    },
    "welcomeSystem": {
      "enabled": false,
      "forSubsOnly": false,
      "forRegOnly": false,
      "DefaultWelcome": "-hugs @nick- Welcome to the stream, @upnick!"
    },
    "twitterSystem": {
      "enabled": true,
      "_comment2": "You need to get your own auth code for this",
      "APIKey": "",
      "APISecret": "",
      "TokenKey": "",
      "TokenSecret": ""
    },
    "youtubeSystem": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "weatherSystem": {
      "enabled": true,
      "authKey": "",
      "_comment3": "You need your own Auth from WeatherUnderground API as well."
    },
    "loyaltySystem": {
      "enabled": false,
      "_comment4": "This feature isn't implemented yet."
    },
    "urlDetection": {
      "enabled": false,
      "defaultTimeout": "600",
      "_comment5": "This feature isn't implemented yet."
    },
    "commands": {
      "Diablo_Command": false,
      "Warcraft_Command": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Suggest you provide the detail on the actual Bot class object and the content of Bot.config

Comment: I added them as per your request.

Comment: Your file with json is not valid: `"BotAdmin": "BotAdmin,` lacks "

Comment: I removed the personal information. I'll fix that for you :P

Comment: The json is valid now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched from doing this a while back to using either SQLite Data Binding as well as .settings file in Visual Studio 2013.

Back when I had this problem the other solution I used is now deprecated but I will leave that code here for now for anyone who needs it.

```
    public string Server = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Server"].ToString();
    public string Port = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Port"].ToString();
    public string Channel = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Channel"].ToString();
    public string OAuth = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["OAuth"].ToString();
    public string Interval = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Interval"].ToString();
    public string Currency = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Currency"].ToString();
    public string Nick = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Nick"].ToString();
    public string BaseAdmin = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BaseAdmin"].ToString();
```

Using JSON as a configuration poses a few problems, one of which is that it will lag my application on startup, writing it can prove difficult as well. So if you're here I suggest you use XML as a configuration or .Settings because they are very viable and faster than use JSON.